# Proper way to include a jQuery library

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a module for Drupal 7. I am using some of the jQuery UI modules which are included.

my natural way to include these is to use `drupal_add_js()` and `drupal_add_css()` with the relevant files. However this feels a little wrong. Is there an official (or better) way to include these libraries, either from Drupal or jQuery.

I tend to find the Drupal/jQuery interface very powerful but frustratingly sparse on documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it! [drupal_add_library()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_add_library/7) does precicely what I wanted, also looks like there are a few other library hooks.

Sorry for answering my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question was in the context of drupal, I found this which I though of putting as my answer:

```
http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/
```

It has a nice explanation on why google hosting is recommended. And it serves all the purposes. Might be helpful for others who come to this page. :)